# Replacing missing values with mean

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am exploring pandas library, and I'd find [this](https://github.com/nyuvis/datasets/blob/master/auto/imports-85.data) dataset. My task is to fill `?` with mean of by group of column `'num-of-doors'`. When I used `dataframe.groupby('num-of-doors').mean()` pandas was unable to find mean of these columns:

> 'peak-rpm', 'price', 'bore', 'stroke', 'normalized-losses', 'horsepower'

So, I tried with my own dataset to know why it is not working. I created a file with the following contents

```
c0,c1,type
1,2,0
2,3,0
2,4,0
1,?,1
1,3,1
```

and I wrote the following script:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data = data.replace('?',np.nan)
print(data)
print(data.groupby('type').mean())
```

this is what I'm getting as output:

```
   c0   c1  type
0   1    2     0
1   2    3     0
2   2    4     0
3   1  NaN     1
4   1    3     1
            c0
type          
0     1.666667
1     1.000000
```

Can you please explain what is going on here? Why I'm not getting mean for column `c1`? Even I tried some Stackoverflow's answers, but still got nothing. Any suggestions?

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `c1`, is not of type numeric, do:

```
data = data.replace('?',np.nan)
data['c1'] = data['c1'].astype(float)
print(data.groupby('type').mean())
```

**Output**

```
            c0   c1
type               
0     1.666667  3.0
1     1.000000  3.0
```

When you read the original *data* DataFrame, as it has a `?` the column is of dtype object (using `dtypes` to verify):

```
c0       int64
c1      object
type     int64
dtype: object
```

If you want to replace the nan, with the mean of the group use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) + [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
data = data.replace('?',np.nan)
data['c1'] = data['c1'].astype(float)

res = data.groupby('type').transform('mean')
print(data.fillna(res))
```

**Output**

```
   c0   c1  type
0   1  2.0     0
1   2  3.0     0
2   2  4.0     0
3   1  3.0     1
4   1  3.0     1
```

As a last advise you could read the csv as:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", na_values='?')
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
   c0   c1  type
0   1  2.0     0
1   2  3.0     0
2   2  4.0     0
3   1  NaN     1
4   1  3.0     1
```

This will save you the need of converting the columns to numeric.

Comment: @HarshilModi Updated the answer showing how to fill na with the mean

Comment: Would this still works for the dataset I found on github? After I replace missing values of `num-of-doors` with 'two'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean 'two'?

Comment: @HarshilModi I updated the answer with another tip

Comment: It's a value for that column. That column can have value either 'four' or 'two'.

Comment: I guess there is no need to type cast (you casted column `c1` as float) data type for [this dataset](https://github.com/nyuvis/datasets/blob/master/auto/imports-85.data).  Pandas does that for us. After I change `read_csv('data.csv')` to `read_csv('data.csv', na_values='?')` I was able to get mean for all remaining fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226558/discussion-between-dani-mesejo-and-harshil-modi).

Answer (score 2):

```
df['c1']=df['c1'].str.replace('[?]','NaN').astype(float)
df.groupby('type').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```